# Get Google Sheet by ID?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I know that Google Apps Script has a [getSheetId() method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getSheetId()) for the Sheet Class, but is there any way to select a sheet within a spreadsheet by referencing the ID?

I don't see anything like getSheetById() in the [Spreadsheet Class documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet).

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can use something like this :

```
function getSheetById(id) {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets().filter(
    function(s) {return s.getSheetId() === id;}
  )[0];
}

var sheet = getSheetById(123456789);
```

And then to find the sheet ID to use for the active sheet, run this and check the Logs or use the debugger.

```
function getActiveSheetId(){
  var id  = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getSheetId();
  Logger.log(id.toString());
  return id;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've been doing that. It just seems very clumsy that you can do SpreadsheetApp.openById() and you can getSheetId(), but you can't select a sheet by ID.

Comment: Careful if you have saved a Sheet id with Properties Service. It may not be exactly the same as the actual Sheet id when you call getProperty(). Make sure you pass Sheet.getSheetId().toString() to the setProperty method instead of just Sheet.getSheetId(). Note: you may need to change the method to deal with Strings.

Comment: You can create a one liner by using `return sheets.find(sheet => sheet.getSheetId() === id)`. Provided that you created a variable named sheets.

Comment: When I use the getSheetById() function proposed by Serge insas or the one-liner proposed by melledijkstra I'm not able to perform any functions like e.g. .getRange() on the returned sheet. Can you tell me what I have to do to make it possible?

Comment: It didn't work for me until I added **toString()** after **s.getSheetId()**. It's because Gogole Script was using ID in scientific notation instead of regular number or string.

Comment: @maxgotstuck did you include the [0]?  I was having the same issue until I realized that was needed as filter returns an array.

Answer (score 12):

```
var sheetActive = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID");
var sheet = sheetActive.getSheetByName("Name");
```

Comment: How does this help select a sheet if you know the sheet ID, but not the sheet name? SpreadsheetApp.openByID opens a spreadsheet, not a sheet.

Comment: @browly This helps because the ID never changes, but if you explicitly write the sheet name and the sheet is renamed the script will no longer work.

Comment: @Xzila SpreadsheetApp.openById() opens a Spreadsheet, not a Sheet, so it doesn't help answer the actual question asked.

Comment: How in the world does this answer have 14 upvotes when it should be deleted?

Answer (score 11):

Look at your URL for query parameter **#gid**

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18K3KY2veYSQGaku8DxEI_a8V1ODEQyIGQCTgwP3uqg4/edit#gid=1962246736

In example above **gid=1962246736**, so you can do something like this:

```
function getSheetNameById_test() {
  Logger.log(getSheetNameById(19622467362));
}

function getSheetNameById(gid) {
  var sheet = getSheetById(gid ?? 0);
  if (null != sheet) {
    return sheet.getName();
  } else {
    return "#N/D";
  }
}

/** 
  * Searches within Active (or a given) Google Spreadsheet for a provided Sheet ID and returns
  * the Sheet if the sheet exists; otherwise it will return undefined if not found.
  *
  * @param {Integer} gid - the ID of a Google Sheet 
  * @param {Spreadsheet} ss - [OPTIONAL] a Google Spreadsheet object (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet)
  * @return {Sheet} the Google Sheet object if found; otherwise undefined (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet)
  */
function getSheetById(gid, ss) {
  var foundSheets = (ss ?? SpreadsheetApp.getActive()).getSheets().filter(sheet => sheet.getSheetId() === gid);
  return foundSheets.length ? foundSheets[0] : undefined;
}
```

Comment: For an unknown reason, the accepted answer doesn't work for me. This classic for each does the magic!

Comment: @Rivo Maybe try what I commented on the first solution?

Comment: @Rodolpho, Please update the link as it seems invalid now.

Comment: @Dhamo sorry for delay, link and source updated

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised this API doesn't exist... It seems essential. In any case, this is what I use in my GAS Utility library:

```
/** 
  * Searches within a given Google Spreadsheet for a provided Sheet ID and returns
  * the Sheet if the sheet exists; otherwise it will return undefined if not found.
  *
  * @param {Spreadsheet} ss - a Google Spreadsheet object (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet)
  * @param {Integer} sheetId - the ID of a Google Sheet 
  * @return {Sheet} the Google Sheet object if found; otherwise undefined (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet)
  */
function getSheetById(ss, sheetId) {
  var foundSheets = ss.getSheets().filter(sheet => sheet.getSheetId() === sheetId);
  return foundSheets.length ? foundSheets[0] : undefined;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple and shortest method for oneliners:

```js
const getSheetById = (spreadsheet, sheet_id) => spreadsheet.getSheets().find(sheet => sheet.getSheetId() === sheet_id)
```

Array.prototype.find returns undefined if there is no match

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use it with more than one sheet you can do the following:

```
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const sheets = ss.getSheets();
const sheetsIds = sheets.map(function(s) { return s.getSheetId() + ''; });

// and then use it like this

const sheet1 = sheets[sheetsIds.indexOf('sheet1_id')];
const sheet2 = sheets[sheetsIds.indexOf('sheet2_id')];
const sheet3 = sheets[sheetsIds.indexOf('sheet3_id')];
```

Answer (score -5):

Not sure about ID but you can set by sheet name:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName("your_sheet_name"));
```

The SpreadsheetApp Class has a [setActiveSheet method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app?hl=en#setActiveSheet(Sheet)) and [getSheetByName method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheetByName(String)).