# Google Scripts Trigger not firing

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

I'm struggling to get my script to auto-run at 6AM (ish). I have the trigger set up to run this script, "Time-Driven", on a "day timer" between "6-7 am". I'm getting no failure notifications (set up to email to me immediately), but the script isn't running. It works exactly as I want it to when I manually run it, but the whole point was to automate it, so I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here. I looked up other instances, and they seem to have been fixed by deleting and re-adding the triggers, but that doesn't solve the issue for me. Is it something in my script preventing an auto-run?

```
function getMessagesWithLabel() {

 var destArray = new Array();
 var label= GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('Personal/Testing');
 var threads = label.getThreads(0,2);

  for(var n in threads){
        var msg = threads[n].getMessages();
        var body = msg[0].getPlainBody();
        var destArrayRow = new Array();
        destArrayRow.push('thread has '+threads[n].getMessageCount()+' messages');
          for(var m in msg){
                     destArrayRow.push(msg[m].getPlainBody());
           }
  destArray.push(destArrayRow);           
        }
Logger.log(destArray);
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
if(ss.getLastRow()==0){sh.getRange(2,1).setValue('getMessagesWithLabel() RESULTS')};
sh.getRange(2,1,destArray.length,destArray[0].length).setValues(destArray);


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, but the reason for this could be that during a trigger there's no "ActiveSpreadsheet" if the script isnt directly linked to spreadsheet (As the spreadsheet is closed). So you should try using:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id); // id is the id of the spreadsheet
                                      // https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/id_is_here/
var sh = ss.getSheetByName(name); // name of the actual sheet ("Sheet 1" for example)
```

Otherwise i see nothing wrong with your code (other than you using label.getThreads(0,2) which sets the maximum number of threads to be brought in to 2, but i assume that's intentional)

Also, you're setting 2,1 instead of what i assume needs to be 1,1 in

```
if(ss.getLastRow()==0){sh.getRange(2,1).setValue('getMessagesWithLabel() RESULTS')};
```

Comment: You are close to the root of the problem. The active spreadsheet is the one the script is bounded to, but there isn't an active sheet as the time-driven trigger doesn't "see" an UI.

Comment: Hmm, okay, this makes sense. The emails that have data that I want come in daily and there's one of each type, so I just need today's two emails, so I limited it to the first two with the label. I tried

    SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getSheetByName(name)

and got "Missing ) after argument list" as my error message, but closed the only two open parenthesis in the code. What am I missing here?

Comment: As long as id and name are defined variables, there is nothing wrong with that. (id should be the id of the spreadsheet and name the name of the sheet, both strings)

i'd bet on a wild ; causing that problem tho.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is due to the use of `getActiveSheet` as it retrieves the sheet displayed on the UI but when your time-driven trigger runs there isn't a sheet displayed on the UI.

Replace getActiveSheet by [getSheetByName](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename) or better get the sheet by it's ID (for details see [Get Google Sheet by ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26682269/1595451))

Reference:

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getactivesheet