# onEdit installable trigger not getting fired when I publish AddOn, but it works fine when I run in my development environment

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, eventtrigger

I have developed googlesheet AddOn. I am creating installable trigger onEdit programatically. It works fine in my development environment. But it's not getting fired when i used published AddOn.

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger("onEdit_Installable")
      .forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet())
      .onEdit()
      .create();

Please help..

Thanks
```

Comment: This has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46649985/6143482).

Comment: But I am using onEdit installable trigger. So for onEdit it should get active spreadsheet. I am not using onTimer trigger. Please help..

Comment: I suspect that getActiveSpreadsheet() doesnt work on simple Triggers. Try changing that to openById(SPREADHSHEET_ID) . If that works, then that proves it.