# Unable to getSheet ID in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I have been trying to get active sheet id from [this answer][1] using:

```
function getActiveSheetId(){
  var id  = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getSheetId();
  Logger.log(id.toString());
  return id;
}
```

but my logger logs 0. Is there some other way to get the same? I want to read this sheet from another sheet file and then perform the operations.

[1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26682269/get-google-sheet-by-id#:~:text=filter(%20function(s)%20%7B,Logs%20or%20use%20the%20debugger.

Comment: When new Spreadsheet is created, the sheet ID of the 1st sheet is `0` as the default value. This is the current specification of Google side. I thought that `0` in your case might be due to this. How about this? But if my understanding of your question is not correct, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the code.

It returns 0 if you apply this function to the first sheet, which is the correct sheet id as you can see from the url of the page:

[image: example1]

and if you apply the same function to a different sheet you get again the correct sheet id:

[image: example2]

---

If you want to **get** a sheet by its id then refer to this post:

[Get Google Sheet by ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26682269/get-google-sheet-by-id)

- **Example:**

  ```
   function getSheetById(id) {
   return SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets().filter(
    function(s) {return s.getSheetId() === id;}
  )[0];
  }
  ```

for example if you want to get the first sheet (id=0) then do that:

```
var sheet = getSheetById(0);
```

And then you can apply all the sheet operations to this `sheet` as usual.